# How do I change the root location for Bash in Windows 10?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have just installed Bash for Windows 10 and it works good.

It keeps its files in `C:\Users\{my user name}\AppData\Local\Lxss`. The main problem is that it is located in the `C:\` directory which has very few space. I want to move it to `D:\`, which has 1 TB of space.

Is it possible to change root folder for Bash in Windows 10?

Comment: I assume that may not be possible, atleast for now. 

[Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/402)

Comment: @Nisheet This issue was last commented about 4 month ago. I hope something changed, because this is huge drawback.

Comment: Unfortunately, this issue is still open and not solved. (root issue can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/449))

Comment: Not that up to speed on Windows but in the DOS 6 days you could join another drive to a directory: http://www.easydos.com/join.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it possible with https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline

```
choco install lxrunoffline
```

- No Internet access required when installing.
- Install any Linux distros to any location on your disk.
- **Moving existing installations to other locations.**
- **Duplicating existing installations. (To create backups.)**
- Register existing installation directories. (For portable usage.)

Comment: At last, it is possible now.

Answer (score 6):

Not yet!

In Win10 Fall Creators Update, we've added the ability to install one or more Linux distros (Ubuntu, openSUSE, SLES, Fedora & others coming soon). Alas, we were not yet able to wrap-up the work required to enable distros to be installed/moved to a non-system drive. We'll be looking into completing this work in a future release.

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted. I hope you will update your answer in future when this feature will be availble.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.D. If I do forget, ping me on twitter and I'll nip over and update this :D https://twitter.com/richturn_ms

Comment: Has there been any update on this? I'd very much like to move my linux installation to my D drive.

Comment: Not yet, but rest assured we're taking a careful look at this scenario.

Comment: Has there been any update on this? I don't why the obsession with system drive.. not everyone have 1TB SSD lying around

Comment: Not yet, but we are working on this issue. While allowing distros to be installed on a non-system drive may at first appear trivial, there are some rough edges that could result in data loss and/or corruption that we have to engineer for. Bear with us.

Comment: any update yet?

Answer (score 1):

It's now possible to specify where you'd like to install your distro in WSL as of [Windows Version 1903](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/whats-new-for-wsl-in-windows-10-version-1903/). Specifically this is possible using the `wsl --export` and `wsl --import` commands.

I'll explain the steps using Ubuntu as a sample distro.

### Step 1: Export your distro

We need to get a .tar file of the minimal Linux root file system (Basically just the userspace stuff, like what a docker container would contain, or the [mini root file system on Alpine Linux's download page](https://alpinelinux.org/downloads/)).

- Export Ubuntu to your current folder to the file ubuntu.tar

  - Run in CMD or Powershell: `wsl --export Ubuntu ubuntu.tar`

### Step 2: Import your distro back

Now we can import our distro back, and specify its install location.

- Create the install location

  - For example: Create 'ubuntuStorage' in D:\
- Import the distro:

  - Run in CMD or Powershell `wsl --import Ubuntu-New D:\ubuntuStorage\ .\ubuntu.tar`
- Optional: Remove your old distro after you verify it works

  - Run in CMD or Powershell `wsl --unregister Ubuntu`

### Some important considerations

As of the time of writing this there are some additional considerations. The first is this distro is now installed without using the Microsoft Store, meaning that you will not be able to use the store app. Instead to run it please run `wsl -d Ubuntu-New` to start it (or set it as your default distro and run `wsl`). Additionally, as of right now you will be logged in as the root user without a way to change the default user. We are tracking that and are working on a fix, you can view updates on the progress [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3974).